# Can someone turn my browser into a RDP with a keylogger?

Tags: web-browser, remote-desktop, scam

I got an email the other day telling me that when I visited a website, someone installed malware in the website with which he was able to use my browser as an RDP. Kinda paranoid right now.

Comment: Possible but very unlikely unless you approved the installation

Comment: See [“Browser started out operating as a RDP having a keylogger” Email Scam](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/browser-started-out-operating-as-a-rdp-having-a-keylogger-email-scam/) - in short: *"... anything it states is just a scam to try and scare you into paying the ransom"*.

Comment: It's probably just spam that you can safely delete. But I would run a malware scan on your computer just in case. Can you link a screenshot of the email?

Comment: "Turning a browser into an RDP" doesn't even make technical sense...